# Select Unique row from the table in sql

Tags: sql

Table

```
Minimum | Maximum   | Price
--------+-----------+------
0.000   |  1.000    |   50.000
0.100   |  1.000    |   60.000  
1.100   |  2.000    |   60.000  
1.000   |  2.000    |   60.000
```

Expected output

```
Minimum  | Maximum   | Price
---------+-----------+---------
0.000    |  1.000    | 50.000
1.100    |  2.000    | 60.000
```

Comment: what did you try till now? and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Your rows are all unique. Do you mean unique price, or anything else? How to chose those rows?

Comment: I have tried this **select *  from #temp e1  where 3-1=(select count(distinct(id)) from #temp e2 where e1.Mini>=e2.Mini and e1.Mini<=e2.Maxi)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `ROW_NUMBER()`, if your RDBMS supports it:

```
SELECT minimum, maximum, price
FROM (
SELECT
    t.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY minimum) rn_min,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY maximum DESC) rn_max
FROM mytable t
) x WHERE rn_min = 1 OR rn_max = 1
```

Or a couple of `NOT EXISTS` conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable t1 WHERE t1.minimum < t.minimum)
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable t2 WHERE t2.maximum > t.maximum)
```

Comment: Not worked for my I have tried this code : select * into #temp2 from #temp e1 where 3-1=(select count(distinct(id)) from #temp e2 where e1.Minimum>=e2.Minimum and e1.Minimum<=e2.Maximum)

Comment: No the syntax would be `INSERT INTO #temp2 SELECT ... FROM #temp ...`

Comment: I have tried this **select *  from #temp e1  where 3-1=(select count(distinct(id)) from #temp e2 where e1.Mini>=e2.Mini and e1.Mini<=e2.Maxi)**

Answer (score 0):

You might find that an approach like this works well:

```
(select t.*
 from #temp t
 order by minimum asc
 fetch first 1 row only
) union all
(select t.*
 from #temp t
 order by minimum desc
 fetch first 1 row only
)
```

Note that `fetch first 1 row only` is standard SQL.  Not all databases support that syntax, typically using `select top (1)` or `limit` instead.

In most databases this will be very fast with an index on `(minimum)` although some would also require an index on `(minimum desc)`.

You can also express this as:

```
select t.*
from #temp t join
     (select min(minimum) as minm, max(minimum) as maxm
      from #temp t
     ) tt
     on t.minimum in (tt.minm, tt.maxm)
```

Comment: Not worked for my I have tried this code  : select * into #temp2 from #temp e1 where 3-1=(select count(distinct(id)) from #temp e2 where e1.Minimum>=e2.Minimum and e1.Minimum<=e2.Maximum)

Comment: @BhanuPratap . . . That query has nothing to do with this answer.

Comment: I have tried this **select *  from #temp e1  where 3-1=(select count(distinct(id)) from #temp e2 where e1.Mini>=e2.Mini and e1.Mini<=e2.Maxi)**